# Libcurl failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed

Tags: ssl, curl, networking, libcurl

I had an issue for the last few days and the hosting technical team wasn't able to help me out, which is why I am asking here. Any information would be highly appreciated.

**Useful Information**

1. Software receives the "schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed" error
2. Software runs inside a VM with a Windows 7 OS
3. Everything runs perfectly fine for 2-3 days and once the issue appears, every single VM on the host experiences the same error.
4. **IF** the issue is present it will **NOT** go away, until **EVERY** single VM has been closed. After waiting 2 minutes I can restart all of the VM's and they will work perfectly fine.
5. **IF** the issue is present I can't access the API inside the VM, but I can inside the host (same IP).
6. **IF** the issue is present and the VM has been restarted it will still receive the issue, until all VM's have been closed and then restarted.
7. **IF** the issue is present and open the website inside the VM I get a network error, but I can access any other website.
8. There is no Firewall or Proxy inside the VM that could cause this issue.
9. The issue **doesn't** occur on every host at the same time and doesn't affect others.
10. We are using the cloud services from Hostinger.
11. No errors appear in the php log file.

**How the issue occurs**

Everythinig runs as expected for 1-2 days without any issues and all of a sudden every single instance on the host receives that error. Other hosts are running perfectly fine, until their 1-2 days pass.

**Fixes that we have tried**

1. Changing Server Location
2. Changing SSL/TLS encryption mode to Flexible
3. Disabling/Enabling Universal SSL
4. Pausing Cloudflare & pointing DNS back to hosting server
5. Forcing different TSL versions inside libcurl
6. Checking if the IP has been banned/blocked

**Code (Most likely not the issue, since restarting the software doesn't fix it)**

```
CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string response;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
    if (curl) {
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: keep-alive");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,endpoint.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
        if (patchOrPOST == "PATCH")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
        }
        else if (patchOrPOST == "PUT")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        }
        else if (patchOrPOST == "GET")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        }
        else if(patchOrPOST=="DELETE")
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
        }
        else
        {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, json.size());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //IS FOR THREADING
        /*
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
        */
        res= curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        if (res!= CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return "ERROR";
        }
        res= curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        if (res!= CURLE_OK) {
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            return "ERROR";
        }
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        long http_code;
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return response;
```

**Error Response which occurs almost instantly after making the request**

```
 *   Trying (OUR IP)...
 * Connected to ourdomain.com (OUR IP) port 443 (#0)
 * schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
 * Closing connection 0
 * schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with ourdomain.com port 443
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error
```

**Screenshots(Error was present on the host)**
[image: API Backend 403 Errors(There are no 500 Errors)]
[image: Accessing the website inside the VM fails, but other websites work]

**My question**
What could be causing this issue and how could I receive better information or even solve this issue?

Comment: You have several issues in the C++ code with passing 0 and 1 to curl parameters, that expect long. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right, I will fix that. Thanks!